# What setting is this defect caused by?

Tags: prusa-i3, extrusion, speed

I am attempting to print the Benchy boat but every attempt so far has been unsuccessful. The print has a sort of slope/blob on the nose of the boat, which emerges after the first 30 layers.

[image: defect]

Here you can see the front of the boat already arching up:

[image: defect 2]

I have tried decreasing speed to 40 mm/s but the issue remains.

**Printer**: Geetech Prusa I3 Pro B

XY Accelleration: 1000 mm/s<sup>2</sup>

XY Jerk: 20 mm/s

Retraction Accelleration: 2000 mm/s<sup>2</sup>

Extruder Jerk: 5 mm/s

Printing Speed: 50 mm/s

Travel Speed: 120 mm/s

Layer Height: 0.1 mm

Infill: 60% (Lines)

Material: PLA, 200 °C, 1.75mm filament, retraction enabled.

Comment: A picture would help tremendously in diagnosing the problem! :)

Comment: Also information regarding your printer, slicer, and type/brand of filament would be useful.

Comment: @NomadMaker Thank you, i have edited the question as you suggested. I was in a bit of a rush yesterday.

Comment: You don't mention cooling, could you elaborate on that in your question? It looks like you are not cooling the deposited filament enough so that it curls up.

Comment: 200C could be way too hot depending on the exact filament and the cooling setup. I'd try 185C and work up from there.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like curling from to much being extruded and no cooling I had the same problem added part cooling and problem was gone

Comment: You address the part cooling part, but you also suggest over-extrusion. Maybe that aspect would be better as a second point. Can you elaborate on part cooling a little to make the answer a little more comprehensive?

Answer (score 0):

The lines along the length of the boat also appear to be wobbling, can you confirm this? Have you used this material before? The layers should look straight and equal.
[image]

I have 2 candidates:
If the lines indeed wobble it may be over extrusion. The excess material pushing the extruded line over the edge. (check the diameter of the filament with a caliper and adjust the extrusion rate if needed)

Or it can be shrinking. 60% infill is quite high. You could try 20 or 30% (less material and more air => less distortion), or adjusting cooling.

Hope it helps, good luck!